# convert multiline to single line in unix

Tags: shell, csv, unix, hive, multiline

I have file which has multi line data in one column, I wanted multi line to be converted to single line.

Here is the sample with Headers

```
final_date|Notes|Status
04/17/2019|"- OB Team - 
Number of Attempt(s): 1
Outcome:other
Order (RMO):0
Campaign : ABC
Additional Notes:  not a working number  
* If any call return to transfer to OB team *"|Complete
04/18/2019|"- OB Team - 

Number of Attempt(s): 3
Outcome: NO ANSWER
Order (RMO): 0
Campaign Name: ABC

*If return call, transfer to OB team* 


- OB TEAM - 
Number of Attempt(s):  1 
Outcome:  VM
Order (RMO):  0
Campaign Name:  ABC 
Additional Notes: None
*If return call, transfer to OB team*"|Complete
```

Above data is has two records. Which I want them to convert to single line and then load to Hive table.

Above data should be converted as below.

```
final_date|Notes|Status
04/17/2019|"- OB Team - Number of Attempt(s): 1 Outcome:other Order (RMO):0 Campaign : ABC Additional Notes:  not a working number * If any call return to transfer to OB team *"|Complete
04/18/2019|"- OB Team - Number of Attempt(s): 3 Outcome: NO ANSWER Order (RMO): 0 Campaign Name: ABC *If return call, transfer to OB team*  - OB TEAM - Number of Attempt(s):  1  Outcome:  VM Order (RMO):  0 Campaign Name:  ABC Additional Notes: None *If return call, transfer to OB team*"|Complete
```

Can someone help me regarding this.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this on your own? What have you tried? And also, shouldn't there be a double-quote at the last line of your sample input before `|Complete`?

Comment: you are right, I did try to remove blank lines, using awk like this. ```awk 'BEGIN{ FS="|"; RS='\n'; OFS = "|" ;} {print;}'``` after that I wanted to concatenate each line until i find | next line. I couldn't get a way to concatenate.

Comment: Okay, do you guarantee there are no double-quotes **inside** second field?

Comment: yes, basically I am getting an excel and converting to CSV. while converting to csv I am getting double quote for this column.

Comment: @subro, you shouldn't parse CSV with line-oriented tools like awk or sed. CSV parsing is done very easily in many programming languages (to name a few, PHP, Perl, Python, Java). Try to solve the problem yourself using one of those languages. I'm sure you'll find answers to your questions here, on SO, without the need to create new post.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, yeah true, as this is bigger file, though of doing with shell commands, if I couldn't achieve with shell, using Python/Java is my second option. Thank you.

Comment: @subro, suppose a cell contains double quotes. Double quotes should be escaped so that each double quote is duplicated, e.g. `abc "string"` becomes `"abc ""string"""`. Provided that a cell value can be multi-line, the parsing task becomes nontrivial for AWK. Unless you really want to write a CSV parser in AWK, I don't see any reason to avoid tools capable of handling the format easily and reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulate output record separator in accordance with the number of double-quotes in current line.

```
awk -F\" 'BEGIN{ors=ORS} NF&&!(NF%2){ORS=(ORS!=ors)?ors:OFS} 1' file
```

Comment: It is working perfectly for the first line, but not for second line.

Comment: @subro, updated, I forgot about blank lines, sorry. does it work now?

Comment: yea, it is working as expected, can you help me understanding this, please.

Comment: @subro It's easy, we're switching output record separator between its original value (`\n` by default, i.e line break) and output field separator (space by default) according to the number of double quotes in current line.

Comment: This way, even if there are multiple broken fields, this will fix them all

Comment: I understand, What you are saying, I still have uncertainty in my mind, can you please share any link/source, which explains in baby steps. Thank you very much.